# AWS DynamoDB | Check if List of Maps contains a specific value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

Im storing user data in AWS DynamoDB. 
One of the attributes is a List of Maps:

```
skills: [
   {
     name: 'foo'
   },
   {
     name: 'bar'
    }
]
```

How can I write a Scan that checks if `skills` have a map with `name` = `foo`?

I'm using [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property)

I have tried using `contains` but can't get it to work with Maps nested in a List:

```
let params: { 
  TableName: 'tablename',
  FilterExpression: 'contains(skills, :val)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':val': 'foo'
  }
}
```